# Add values named per element in loop

Tags: json, bash

I have the next piece of code:

```
echo -n "{ \"data\":" > test.json
echo -n "  [" >> test.json

sqcur=0
sqtotal=`ls /etc/squid?.conf | wc -l`
tcp_ports=$(grep "port" /etc/squid?.conf |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's|.*[0-9]*\:||g'|sort|uniq|xargs)

for squidconf in `ls /etc/squid?.conf`; do
  let "sqcur+=1" > /dev/null
  squidident=`echo $squidconf | sed 's/.*\///' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`
  tcp_ports=$(grep "port" $squidconf |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's|.*[0-9]*\:||g'|sort|uniq|xargs)  
  if [ $sqcur -lt $sqtotal ]; then
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }," >> test.json
  else
    echo -n "    { \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\", \"{#SQPROC_PORT}\": \"${tcp_ports}\", \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }" >> test.json  
  fi
done

echo -n "  ]" >> test.json
echo "}" >> test.json
```

It gives the next content in json file:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
                "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid1",
                "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid1.conf",
                "{#SQPROC_PORT}": "1111 2222",
                "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid1.conf"
            },
```

But I want in case of multiple values of port to obtain the next result:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "{#SQPROC}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid",
                "{#SQPROC_IDENT}": "squid1",
                "{#SQPROC_ARGS}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid1.conf",
                "{#SQPROC_PORT_1111}": "1111",
                "{#SQPROC_PORT_2222}": "2222",
                "{#SQPROC_CONF}": "/etc/squid1.conf"
            },
```

Could you please help with it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a something like this:

```
for port in $tcpports
do
     all_ports="${all_ports} \"{#SQPROC_PORT_$port}\": \"$port\","
done
```

At the end of this loop you'll have an `all_ports` variable containing something like:

```
"{#SQPROC_PORT_1111}": "1111", "{#SQPROC_PORT_2222}": "2222",
```

for example.

To integrate that easily in the code you already have I would propose some little changes in your `for`-loop. For each iteration build up a variable `json_content` that will containt the data for the json at that iteration and at the end of the iteration, just print `$json_content`:

```
echo -n "{ \"data\":" > test.json
echo -n "  [" >> test.json

sqcur=0
sqtotal=`ls /etc/squid?.conf | wc -l`

for squidconf in `ls /etc/squid?.conf`; do
    let "sqcur+=1" > /dev/null
    squidident=`echo $squidconf | sed 's/.*\///' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'`
    tcp_ports=$(grep "port" $squidconf |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's|.*[0-9]*\:||g'|sort|uniq|xargs)  
    json_content="{ \"{#SQPROC}\": \"/usr/local/squid/bin/squid\", \"{#SQPROC_IDENT}\": \"${squidident}\", \"{#SQPROC_ARGS}\": \"-D -C -F -f ${squidconf}\","
    for port in $tcp_ports
    do
         json_content="$json_content \"{#SQPROC_PORT_$port}\": \"$port\","
    done
    json_content="$json_content \"{#SQPROC_CONF}\": \"${squidconf}\" }"
    if [ $sqcur -lt $sqtotal ]; then
        json_content="${json_content},"
    fi
    echo -n "    ${json_content}" >> test.json
done

echo -n "  ]" >> test.json
echo "}" >> test.json
```

I can't verify the rest of the loop. I have no squid! But as you re-calculate the `tcp_ports` in the for-loop, I removed the initialization before the for-loop

Hope this helps,
Good luck!